# Paypal Donation Button Return URL variables

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Is it possible to have the return URL on a regular donate button email a receipt to the payer with custom variables?  If so, where can I find a list of these return variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, and the return URL can be set up so as to contain all the POST variables you sent to PayPal, but you havent' received the money yet, so it is no time to be issuing a receipt. What you could issue is an *order acknowledgement,* or, this being a donation, a 'thank you'. The correct time to issue a receipt is *when you get the money,* which you can discover in a number of ways, e.g. via Instant Payment Notification (IPN).

Comment: where can I find the variable list to do this?

Comment: Just search for 'Paypal HTML Variables': the one you want is 'rm' (return method).

Comment: Can you provide some sample code just to get be started? PHP